# Is there a better way of writing this with use-package?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, eshell, use-package

I feel like there is a better way of writing this with `use-package` but I just can't get the usual way to work.

```lisp
(use-package eshell
  :hook
  (eshell-mode
   . (lambda ()
       (define-key
         eshell-mode-map
         (kbd "C-<backspace>")
         (lambda () ; clear shell
           (interactive)
           (message "I am some other function"))))))
```

I tried using the `:bind (:map eshell-mode-map ("C-<backspace>" . <lambda here>))`, but that just binds the function to the global key map for some reason. Maybe because `eshell-mode-map` is `nil` till eshell is launched. Could someone suggest a better utilisation of use-package to write what I already have?

Answer (score 1):

The keybindings created with `:bind` expect a function name (not sure how lambdas are expanded) so you can define a named function in the `:init` clause of `use-package` which should work as expected...

```lisp
(use-package eshell
  :after esh-mode
  :init 
  (defun my-clear-shell ()
    (interactive)
    (message "I am some other function"))
  :bind (:map 
     eshell-mode-map
     ("C-<backspace>" . my-clear-shell)))
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I get a `Symbol’s value as variable is void: eshell-mode-map`. You can solve that by adding a `:after esh-mode` but then the keybinding is available everywhere and not just in eshell-mode.

Comment: I get the same error without the `:after esh-mode` line (and added to the answer) but keybindings work as expected.

Comment: ...in eshell `<C-backspace> runs the command my-clear-shell (found in
eshell-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘~/.emacs’.`

Comment: ...and elsewhere `<C-backspace> runs the command backward-kill-word (found in
global-map), which is an interactive native compiled Lisp function in
‘simple.el’.`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your config to keep it simple:

```
(defun your-eshell-clear ()
  (interactive)
  (message "TODO impl your-eshell-clear"))

(defun your-eshell-setup ()
  (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "C-<backspace>") #'your-eshell-clear))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'your-eshell-setup)
```

You can simplly put it to your init file, it will not slow your Emacs startup. If you need, you can group it via `progn` or `with-eval-after-load` or `use-package`, thought they does not provide actual benefits, and `use-package` sometimes can make your init file more complex and harder to understand.